# Kafka Stream Ksql Json

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

Does kafka stream / Ksql actually support json natively somehow? What are the other formats supported ? I have seen that is it possible to have flat json interpreted as table. I want to understand that part a bit better; what are the other formats that kafka-streams via Ksql that can be queried via SQL? How is that possible or supported? What's the native support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**KSQL**

For Value formats, KSQL Supports AVRO, JSON and DELIMITED (like CSV).

You can find the documentation here:

- https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/syntax-reference.html

**Kafka Streams**

Kafka Streams comes with some primitive/basic SerDes (Serializers / Deserializers) under the `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization` package.

You can find the documentation here:

- https://kafka.apache.org/22/documentation/streams/developer-guide/datatypes.html

[image]

Confluent also provides **schema-registry compatible Avro SerDes** for data in generic Avro and in specific Avro format. You can find the documentation here:

- https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/datatypes.html#avro

You can also use **basic SerDe implementation for JSON** that comes with the examples:

- https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.2/streams/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/examples/pageview/PageViewTypedDemo.java#L83

As a last resort, you can always **create your own custom SerDes**. For that, you must:

1. Write a serializer for your data type `T` by implementing
   `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer`.
2. Write a deserializer for `T` by implementing
   `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer`.
3. Write a serde for `T` by implementing
   `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde`, which you either do
   manually (see existing SerDes in the previous section) or by
   leveraging helper functions in Serdes such as
   `Serdes.serdeFrom(Serializer<T>, Deserializer<T>)`. Note that you will
   need to implement your own class (that has no generic types) if you
   want to use your custom serde in the configuration provided to
   KafkaStreams. If your serde class has generic types or you use
   `Serdes.serdeFrom(Serializer<T>, Deserializer<T>)`, you can pass your
   serde only via methods calls (for example
   `builder.stream("topicName", Consumed.with(...))`).